# FTP ListDirectory command returns status code 125

Tags: c#, ftp

I have a bit of code that is supposed to check whether a directory exists on a remote server. It executes the `ListDirectory` command on the path and expects a response if it exists and an exception if it doesn't.

The problem is that the command returns the code `125 DataAlreadyOpen`, so my code interprets that as success, when it should have failed.

I might be completely misunderstanding how FTP works. I'm creating a new request every time, so I don't understand how a connection can already be open.

Oh, and the code works with root directories like `ftp://myIP/Folder1`, but doesn't work with `ftp://myIP/Folder1/Folder2`. I'm using the IIS FTP server, by the way.

```
public static bool DirectoryExists(string path)
{
    try
    {
        var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(path);
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("foo", "bar");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
        request.KeepAlive = false;

        using (var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

How can I reliably check whether a directory exists? All the code examples I've found use this technique.

Comment: does using `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.PrintWorkingDirectory` instead of `ListDirectory` work ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta See naveen's answer. Different response, but doesn't do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this issue by using the `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory` command whenever I want to check if a directory exists. If it doesn't exist, it's created, if it exists, I catch the exception and carry on.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the request.Method to

```
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.PrintWorkingDirectory;
```

Comment: Then the response code is `257 PathnameCreated`, but the directory still doesn't exist on the server.